# Serialization of item's fields by different name

Tags: scrapy

Is there a way to have scrapy fields to be serialized under a different name? For example field 'product_name' would become 'product name'.

```
    class PropertyItem(Item):
        product_name = Field()
```

then

```
    l.add_xpath('product_name','//[@id="some_id"]/text()')
```

will be serialized as 'product_name': "some value", while i want it to be 'some other name': "some value"

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I completely understand you but you can always use [item pipelines](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html) to edit and change the items your spider returns.

For example, you can do something like this:

```
class FooPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        new_value = item['product_name'] + ' new name'
        del item['product_name']
        item['some other name'] = new_value
        return item
```

By default scrapy.Item fields are static and only defined fields can be set. You can avoid this by overriding `__setitem__()` magic method:

```
class TestItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._values[key] = value
```

And result:

```
t = TestItem()
t['name2'] = 'one'
print(t)
>>> {'name2': 'one'}
# even though name2 is not defined
```

Comment: Pipeline doesn't let change item fields 
2016-11-14 21:30:14 [scrapy] ERROR: Error processing {'URL': 'http://www.example.com/kit400.html',
 'product_name': 'aa 400',
 ...}
Tra:
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/pipelines.py", line 30, in process_item
    item[new_key] = value
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scrapy/item.py", line 63, in __setitem__
    (self.__class__.__name__, key))
KeyError: 'CatalogsItem does not support field: Product Name'

Comment: @AlonS it just says that your item doesn't have that field in the specification. Just add `new_key` to your `CatalogsItem`, as in `new_key = scrapy.Field()` like you would do with any field.

Comment: that's correct but given i want to rename it to a field with spaces in its name there is no way to do it. `new key = Field()` wouldn't go

Comment: @AlonS You can hack through this in several ways, however it's important to note that scrapy.Item is just an extensions of your normal python dictionary and both are interchangeable when it comes to scrapy so you can actually just ignore all of these field definitions and just use python dictionary instead of scrapy.Item. Dictionaries don't have static keys so yo can just add any key you want at any time.

Comment: since the question was - if there are a way to serialize scrapy.field under different field name i can't accept your answer. Would you like to edit it in accordance with your last comment, saying there is no way to do it with scrapy.Item+scrapy.Field? I would accept that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you define additional fields in the `__init__` method or your `Item` class, you are less restricted in choosing their names:

```
class TestItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fields["product name"] = scrapy.Field()
```